# В бд заносятся не все данные

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток. Возникла такая проблема: если пытаюсь занести данные в базу MySQL из PHP то заносятся не все данные. Например вот данные которые нужно занести:

"ArbuzzzzZ: Единственное похожее, что я до этого встречал, это когда друг прислал мне ворд с картинкой, на которой была ссылка на дропбокс, где лежал qr-code со ссылкой на Яндекс.Диск с архивом с txt-файлом, в котором была ссылка на YouTube, по которой открывалось трехсекундное видео, на котором этот самый друг снимал распечатку скриншота экрана, где в Ворде было написано расписание пар на завтра, которое я у него, собственно, и просил…
faddistr: Вы, видно, его очень достали." а заносится только "ArbuzzzzZ: ".

Но, если скопировать запрос, который генерируется в РНР и вручную воткнуть в phpMyAdmin то все заносится нормально. вот код:

```
$DATES = mysql _ real _ escape_string(trim($text->find('span[class=date]',0)->plaintext));

$RATINGS = $rating;

$TEXTS =mysql_real_escape_string(trim($text->find('div[class=text]',0)));

$query = "INSERT INTO `quotes` (`text`,`date`,`rating`) VALUES ('$TEXTS','$DATES','$RATINGS')";
                    mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

Answer (score 2):

Немного не понятно, что вы имели ввиду под "не все данные", но тем не менее попробую угадать.

1. Если Вы имели ввиду, что данный параграф не заносится вообще, а заносятся только другие значения, которые Вы передаете в values, то, вероятно, необходимо проверить то, что хранится в переменных, которые вы вставляете в запрос с помощью echo или var_dump, вероятно проблема в том, что некорректно берутся данные из DOM-а (всего кода не вижу, так что точно сказать не могу)
2. Однако скорее всего Вы имели ввиду то, что у Вас не весь текст заносится в таблицу. Тогда обратите внимание каким методом (GET, POST, etc...) данные передаются с клиента на сервер, т.к., например, у метода GET есть ограничение по длине и он "обрезает" слишком "длинные" данные, которые передаются с его помощью на сервер.

Comment: именно 2) Вы угадали) не весь текст заносится. Но вот в чем загвоздка. я просто пытаюсь сграбить контент и у меня на странице нет никаких форм чтобы я мог указать метод... просьба сильно не ругать за тупость - я пока только начинаю учиться)

Comment: Хотелось бы знать тогда где именно прерывается текст, на каком символе. И да, функцию mysql_real_escape_string лучше потихоньку отучаться юзать. она deprecated с версии 5.5.

Comment: спасибо за совет, учту.(а что использовать посоветуете?) текст прерывается на символах двоеточия или, если его нет, то на угловой скобке. P.S. сам запрос выглядит правильно - то есть там весь текст - я выводил прям каждый проверял.

Comment: Какого типа поле в базе (с указанием размера пожалуйста)? И что будет, если убрать все двойные кавычки внутри текста?

Comment: тип поля просто текст. двойных ковычек текст не содержит

Comment: Хоть просто text и не очень хорошо использовать, пока пойдет. Ничего страшного не будет.
Хотел бы уточнить, на всякий случай, на каком двоеточии прерывается текст? И что значит двойных кавычек нет, когда я их вижу сверху в вопросе? Или у Вас там одинарные кавычки подразумеваются?

Comment: Я бы ещё кодировки проверил. Не знаю, чем именно парсится DOM, но обрыв на первом нелатинском символе `ArbuzzzzZ: `... наталкивает на мысли.

Comment: те ковычки это чтобы процитировать. это я вписал сюда. в оригинале их нету. Скорее всего это действительно кодировка, ибо когда перевожу в другую(например Windows-1251) заносятся кракозябры но все(то есть сообщение полностью)